# Creating a TreeMap visualization

Tags: java, python, visualization

I want the algorithm for creating a Treemap visualization.

Something like this: [An Easy Way to Make a Treemap](http://flowingdata.com/2010/02/11/an-easy-way-to-make-a-treemap/)

Problem is that I do not want to use R ... and I want the source-code. Preferably in Python or Java.

Thing is that I have to customize it ... instead of colors I want images, so something that gives me coordinates would be awesome.

Thanks,

Answer (score 10):

The [TreeMap Java Library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/treemap/) on SourceForge.net is an open source implementation of the 
algorithm described in [Ben Schneiderman's paper](http://www.cs.umd.edu/local-cgi-bin/hcil/rr.pl?number=91-06).

There is also a reference implementation linked to from Schneiderman's [Treemap History page](http://www.cs.umd.edu/hcil/treemap-history/).

Answer (score 4):

The [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treemapping) seems to have some good links at the end.

I'd probably first try the easy approach of recursion and proportional division. At first level of the tree, divide the target area vertically (each area here is a branch, area size depends on branch size):

```
+-------+-------+-------+
|       |       |       |
|       |       |       |
|       |       |       |
|       |       |       |
|       |       |       |
|       |       |       |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

At second level, divide horizontally:

```
+-------+-------+-------+
|       |       |       |
+-------+       |       |
|       +-------+       |
|       |       |       |
|       |       +-------+
|       |       |       |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

At third level divide vertically again:

```
+--+----+----+--+----+--+
|  |    |    |  |    |  |
+--+-+--+    |  |    |  |
|    |  +-+--+--+    |  |
|    |  | |     |    |  |
|    |  | |     +---++--+
|    |  | |     |   |   |
+----+--+-+-----+---+---+
```

Etc.

Answer (score 2):

[This is another good starter](http://www.cs.umd.edu/hcil/treemap-history/) - a LOT to read and an archive containing treemap algorithms. The visualization part may be missing.

Answer (score 2):

[Prefuse](http://prefuse.org/) also has implemented a TreeMap.  Here's an [example](http://prefuse.org/gallery/treemap/).  Here's the [code for the example](http://prefuse.org/gallery/treemap/TreeMap.java).

Answer (score 2):

IBM ManyEyes let you show your data as Treemap:

http://www-958.ibm.com/software/data/cognos/manyeyes/page/Treemap.html

It takes table data as input. The result is interactive you can get details for each part of the treemap, filter and re-organize the treemap.

Drawbacks are the lack of customization (color scale, ..) and the heaviness of Java.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a JavaScript library that will take care of the algorithm side and focus only on the presentation part with manipulating the CSS.

Check out for example D3: http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/treemap.html

You can add for each of the divs

```
background-image: url('path/to/image.png');
```

Comment: The question is about java or python not javascript.